# How to use ngBind with multiple filters in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters, ng-bind

I have a ngModel `data.type` which is bound and I want to apply a filter `actionType` to it first and then add a prefix and then finally pass it to `localize` filter.

Something like:

```
<h3 data-ng-bind="'prefix.' + {{ data.type | actionType}} | localize "></h3>
```

So for e.g. if `actionType` filter returned `my-action-type` then I want to pass `prefix.my-action-type` to `localize` filter.

Is there anyway to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control the order of operations in angular expressions by wrapping an expression in parentheses, just like you can in javascript.

If you have nested parentheses, they are executed before their containing parentheses, and it should all happen left to right.

`<h3 data-ng-bind="('prefix.' + (data.type | actionType)) | localize "></h3>`